# JSON eliminar claves con su valor (Vacío) en javascript

Tags: javascript, json, recursión, objeto

Tengo un json a validar y quiero eliminar los valores vacios o con la palabra `'Vacío'` para no tener datos innecesarios

```
var objeto = {clave1:"hola",clave2:"Vacío",clave3:""}
```

la idea seria eliminar la `clave2` porque tiene el valor Vacío y la `calve3` porque esta vacía (`""`) esto es fácil seria algo así

```js
var objeto = {clave1:"hola",clave2:"Vacío",clave3:""}

for (var clave in objeto) {
    if(objeto[clave]==""||objeto[clave]=="Vacío"){
     delete objeto[clave] //eliminamos solo las claves vacias
    }
  }
  
console.log(objeto)
```

El problema es cuando el **json** es muy complejo y tiene muchos objetos hijos y hay que validar todos y quitarles las claves vacias sin saber la forma o el orden del objeto

**JSON a validar**

```js
var objeto = 
  {
    "state": "",
    "title": "Evaluador",
    "tituloPadre": "",
    "id": 26,
    "data": {
      "tipoLicencia": 26,
      "categorias": 0,
      "nroLicencia": {
        "valor": "1234",
        "activo": true
      },
      "fechaEmision": {
        "valor": "16-12-2017",
        "activo": true
      },
      "fechaVencimiento": {
        "valor": "22-12-2017",
        "activo": true
      },
      "estatus": {
        "valor": "2",
        "activo": true
      },
      "horasTotalesVuelo": {
        "valor": "21",
        "activo": true
      },
      "observacionesImpresasLicencia": {
        "valor": "sdfg",
        "activo": true
      },
      "soporteCargarLicencias": {
        "valor": "Vacío",
        "activo": true
      },
      "habilitacionesClase": {
        "clasificacionHabilitacion": 1,
        "activo": true,
        "registros": [
          {
            "idTipoHabilitacion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 0
            },
            "idFuncion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 7
            },
            "manufactura": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 5
            },
            "modelo": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 4
            },
            "siglasTipoDesignador": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 3
            },
            "tipoAeronave": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 0
            },
            "cantidadMotores": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 2
            },
            "fechaVencimiento": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 6
            },
            "estatus": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 8
            },
            "tipoMotor": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 1
            },
            "soporte": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": false,
              "index": 0
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "habilitacionesTipo": {
        "clasificacionHabilitacion": 2,
        "activo": true,
        "registros": [
          {
            "idTipoHabilitacion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 0
            },
            "idFuncion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 7
            },
            "manufactura": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 5
            },
            "modelo": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 4
            },
            "siglasTipoDesignador": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 3
            },
            "tipoAeronave": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 0
            },
            "cantidadMotores": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 2
            },
            "fechaVencimiento": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 6
            },
            "estatus": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 8
            },
            "tipoMotor": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 1
            },
            "soporte": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 9
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "habilitacionesEspeciales": {
        "clasificacionhabilitacion": 3,
        "activo": false,
        "vueloInstrumental": {
          "activo": true,
          "idTipoHabilitacion": {
            "clave": "",
            "valor": 17,
            "edit": "false"
          },
          "fechaVencimiento": {
            "clave": "Vacío",
            "valor": "",
            "edit": "false"
          },
          "estatus": {
            "clave": "Vacío",
            "valor": "",
            "edit": "false"
          }
        },
        "fumigacionAerea": {
          "activo": true,
          "registros": [
            {
              "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 0
              },
              "idFuncion": {
                "clave": "",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 7
              },
              "manufactura": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 5
              },
              "modelo": {
                "clave": "",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 4
              },
              "siglasTipoDesignador": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 3
              },
              "tipoAeronave": {
                "clave": "",
                "valor": "",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 0
              },
              "cantidadMotores": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 2
              },
              "fechaVencimiento": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 6
              },
              "estatus": {
                "clave": "",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 8
              },
              "tipoMotor": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "Vacío",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 1
              },
              "soporte": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "",
                "edit": "false",
                "index": 9
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "competenciaLinguistica": {
        "clasificacionhabilitacion": 4,
        "activo": false,
        "registros": [
          {
            "nivel": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 0
            },
            "duracion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 1
            },
            "fechaVencimiento": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 2
            },
            "estatus": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "habilitaciones": {
        "clasificacionHabilitacion": 5,
        "activo": false,
        "idTipoHabilitacion": {
          "clave": "Vacío",
          "valor": "",
          "edit": "false"
        },
        "fechaVencimiento": {
          "clave": "",
          "valor": "",
          "edit": "false"
        },
        "estatus": {
          "clave": "Vacío",
          "valor": "Vacío",
          "edit": "false"
        }
      },
      "habilitacionesRpa": {
        "clasificacionHabilitacion": 6,
        "activo": false,
        "registros": [
          {
            "idTipoHabilitacion": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 0
            },
            "fechaVencimiento": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 1
            },
            "estatus": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "habilitacionesTripulanteVuelo": {
        "clasificacionHabilitacion": 5,
        "activo": false,
        "registros": [
          {
            "idTipoHabilitacion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 0
            },
            "fechaVencimiento": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 1
            },
            "estatus": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false",
              "index": 2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  

  console.log(objeto)
```

Comment: Simplemente por aclarar: JSON es un tipo de notación, como XML. No hay objetos JSON, hay objetos en Javascript, que se pueden representar en texto con notación JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para iterar un **JSON** dinamicamente sin saber su tamaño o forma podemos usar una funcion re cursiva

## Terminos

**Recursividad**

Como definición general, podemos decir que una función recursiva es aquella que se llama a si misma para resolverse. Dicho de otra manera, una función recursiva se resuelve con una llamada a si misma, cambiando el valor de un parámetro en la llamada a la función. A través de las sucesivas llamadas recursivas a la función se van obteniendo valores que, computados, sirven para obtener el valor de la función llamada originalmente.

---

**typeof**

El operador typeof devuelve una cadena que indica el tipo del operando sin evaluarlo. operando es la cadena, variable, palabra clave u objeto para el que se devolverá su tipo. Los paréntesis son opcionales.

---

### Solucion

para resolver este problema creamos una funcion re cursiva que se llama a si misma cuando se cumpla una condición,en este caso hay que preguntar por el tipo de elemento si es un objeto entonces volvemos a ejecutar la misma funcion con el parametro del objeto que en ese momento esta siendo iterado y así hasta recorrerlo todo.

```
function eliminarVacios(jsonx){ <--- funcion recursiva
 for (var clave in jsonx) { <--- for que itera el json pasado como parametro
  if(typeof jsonx[clave] == 'string'){ <-- preguntamos si es un 'string'
    if(jsonx[clave] == 'Vacío'||jsonx[clave] == ''){ <-- validamos si esta vacio o contiene la palabra 'Vacío'
      delete jsonx[clave] <-- eliminamos la clave que este vacia o contenga la palabra 'Vacío'
    }
  } else if (typeof jsonx[clave] == 'object') { <-- preguntamos si es un 'objeto'
    eliminarVacios(jsonx[clave]) <-- volvemos a ejecutar la funcion recursiva
  }
 }
}
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
var objeto = 
      {
        "state": "",
        "title": "Evaluador",
        "tituloPadre": "",
        "id": 26,
        "data": {
          "tipoLicencia": 26,
          "categorias": 0,
          "nroLicencia": {
            "valor": "1234",
            "activo": true
          },
          "fechaEmision": {
            "valor": "16-12-2017",
            "activo": true
          },
          "fechaVencimiento": {
            "valor": "22-12-2017",
            "activo": true
          },
          "estatus": {
            "valor": "2",
            "activo": true
          },
          "horasTotalesVuelo": {
            "valor": "21",
            "activo": true
          },
          "observacionesImpresasLicencia": {
            "valor": "sdfg",
            "activo": true
          },
          "soporteCargarLicencias": {
            "valor": "Vacío",
            "activo": true
          },
          "habilitacionesClase": {
            "clasificacionHabilitacion": 1,
            "activo": true,
            "registros": [
              {
                "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 0
                },
                "idFuncion": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 7
                },
                "manufactura": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 5
                },
                "modelo": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 4
                },
                "siglasTipoDesignador": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 3
                },
                "tipoAeronave": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 0
                },
                "cantidadMotores": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 2
                },
                "fechaVencimiento": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 6
                },
                "estatus": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 8
                },
                "tipoMotor": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 1
                },
                "soporte": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": false,
                  "index": 0
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "habilitacionesTipo": {
            "clasificacionHabilitacion": 2,
            "activo": true,
            "registros": [
              {
                "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 0
                },
                "idFuncion": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 7
                },
                "manufactura": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 5
                },
                "modelo": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 4
                },
                "siglasTipoDesignador": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 3
                },
                "tipoAeronave": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 0
                },
                "cantidadMotores": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 2
                },
                "fechaVencimiento": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 6
                },
                "estatus": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 8
                },
                "tipoMotor": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 1
                },
                "soporte": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 9
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "habilitacionesEspeciales": {
            "clasificacionhabilitacion": 3,
            "activo": false,
            "vueloInstrumental": {
              "activo": true,
              "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                "clave": "",
                "valor": 17,
                "edit": "false"
              },
              "fechaVencimiento": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "",
                "edit": "false"
              },
              "estatus": {
                "clave": "Vacío",
                "valor": "",
                "edit": "false"
              }
            },
            "fumigacionAerea": {
              "activo": true,
              "registros": [
                {
                  "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 0
                  },
                  "idFuncion": {
                    "clave": "",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 7
                  },
                  "manufactura": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 5
                  },
                  "modelo": {
                    "clave": "",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 4
                  },
                  "siglasTipoDesignador": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 3
                  },
                  "tipoAeronave": {
                    "clave": "",
                    "valor": "",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 0
                  },
                  "cantidadMotores": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 2
                  },
                  "fechaVencimiento": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 6
                  },
                  "estatus": {
                    "clave": "",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 8
                  },
                  "tipoMotor": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "Vacío",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 1
                  },
                  "soporte": {
                    "clave": "Vacío",
                    "valor": "",
                    "edit": "false",
                    "index": 9
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "competenciaLinguistica": {
            "clasificacionhabilitacion": 4,
            "activo": false,
            "registros": [
              {
                "nivel": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 0
                },
                "duracion": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 1
                },
                "fechaVencimiento": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 2
                },
                "estatus": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 3
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "habilitaciones": {
            "clasificacionHabilitacion": 5,
            "activo": false,
            "idTipoHabilitacion": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false"
            },
            "fechaVencimiento": {
              "clave": "",
              "valor": "",
              "edit": "false"
            },
            "estatus": {
              "clave": "Vacío",
              "valor": "Vacío",
              "edit": "false"
            }
          },
          "habilitacionesRpa": {
            "clasificacionHabilitacion": 6,
            "activo": false,
            "registros": [
              {
                "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 0
                },
                "fechaVencimiento": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 1
                },
                "estatus": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 2
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "habilitacionesTripulanteVuelo": {
            "clasificacionHabilitacion": 5,
            "activo": false,
            "registros": [
              {
                "idTipoHabilitacion": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 0
                },
                "fechaVencimiento": {
                  "clave": "",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 1
                },
                "estatus": {
                  "clave": "Vacío",
                  "valor": "Vacío",
                  "edit": "false",
                  "index": 2
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }


  function eliminarVacios(jsonx){
    for (var clave in jsonx) {
      if(typeof jsonx[clave] == 'string'){
        if(jsonx[clave] == 'Vacío'||jsonx[clave] == ''){
          delete jsonx[clave]
        }
      } else if (typeof jsonx[clave] == 'object') {
        eliminarVacios(jsonx[clave])
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  eliminarVacios(objeto)
  console.log(objeto)
```